# Convert Postgresql into HiveSql

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, hive, hiveql

How do I convert below mentioned postgresql query into HiveSql

```
SELECT
    COUNT(user_id) Total_profiles,
    COUNT(user_id) FITLER (WHERE profile_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-03-31') as Q1_profile,
    COUNT(user_id) FITLER (WHERE profile_date BETWEEN '2020-04-01' AND '2020-06-30') as Q2_profile,
    COUNT(user_id) FITLER (WHERE profile_date BETWEEN '2020-07-01' AND '2020-09-30') as Q3_profile,
    COUNT(user_id) FITLER (WHERE profile_date BETWEEN '2020-010-01' AND '2020-12-31') as Q4_profile
FROM 
    customer_profiles
WHERE 
    profile_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CASE expressions like this:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(user_id) Total_profiles,
    COUNT(case when profile_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-03-31' then user_id else null end) as Q1_profile,
    COUNT(case when profile_date BETWEEN '2020-04-01' AND '2020-06-30' then user_id else null end) as Q2_profile,
    COUNT(case when profile_date BETWEEN '2020-07-01' AND '2020-09-30' then user_id else null end) as Q3_profile,
    COUNT(case when profile_date BETWEEN '2020-10-01' AND '2020-12-31' then user_id else null end) as Q4_profile
FROM 
    customer_profiles
WHERE 
    profile_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'
```

Also in Hive version >= 1.3 you can use `quarter` function:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(user_id) Total_profiles,
    COUNT(case when quarter(profile_date)=1 then user_id else null end) as Q1_profile,
    COUNT(case when quarter(profile_date)=2 then user_id else null end) as Q2_profile,
    COUNT(case when quarter(profile_date)=3 then user_id else null end) as Q3_profile,
    COUNT(case when quarter(profile_date)=4 then user_id else null end) as Q4_profile
FROM 
    customer_profiles
WHERE 
    profile_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'
```